# Crystal report formula workshop simple if not working

Tags: crystal-reports

I have to make a simple change to a report done by another developer and if I edit the "ShowAverageSpeed" formula in VS2010 I can see the formula as:
if ({AXMXmlJob.AverageSpeed} = 0 ) Then "Stopped" Else  "Moving"

I save the formula in the Formula Workshop but when I try to view the report on the website I get: "A string is required here."

If I remove this from the report it renders fine so I am sure this is where the error is. AXMXmlJob.AverageSpeed is nvarchar(50) null but if I try to use if ({AXMXmlJob.AverageSpeed} = "0" ) the it complains that it is expecting a number?

Comment: Would you please post what the formula contained when you started? When you see "A string is required here," what part of the formula does Crystal highlight?

Comment: I solved this thanks. I tracked it down to the fact that AXMXmlJob.AverageSpeed is a string.... so I had to do ToNumber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs the same data type on both ends.  Try this:

if (ToNumber({AXMXmlJob.AverageSpeed}) = 0 ) Then "Stopped" Else "Moving"

Comment: I saw some answer stating the data types must be the same but I never guessed that mine was in the if part. Now I know why I hate Crystal. Thanks!!